# Problems with look up search

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a macro that compares 2 values held in `Column L` and `Column N`. The following code keeps

```
Set SpareCell = Range("R1")
Set BlankCell = Range("L14")
Count = 0
Count2 = 0

Do While BlankCell <> ""
    Do While SpareCell <> ""
        If BlankCell.Offset(Count) = SpareCell.Offset(Count2) Then
            Range(BlankCell.Offset(Count), BlankCell.Offset(Count, -11)).Copy
            Range(BlankCell.Offset(EndOfCredits), BlankCell.Offset(EndOfCredits, -11)).PasteSpecial
            BlankCell.Offset(EndOfCredits) = SpareCell.Offset(Count2, -1)
            EndOfCredits = EndOfCredits + 1
        End If
        Count2 = Count2 + 1
    Loop
    Count = Count + 1
Loop
```

The macro crashes at the line after the second do while. Any ideas gratefully received.

Basically, the data starting at `L14` consists on invoice numbers. The data starting at `R1` also consists of invoice numbers and the data to the left of it in `Q1` are the invoice numbers that were merged in the invoice in `R`. This can occur more than once so `Vlookup` won't work. The copy and paste code hopefully copies the data in the line `A-L` where there is a match and pastes it at the bottom, which is held in `EndOfCredits`. The Value in `Q` is then pasted in place of the value in `L`

Sorry - I don't have enough reputation to post a screenshot - hard to believe, I know!

Comment: Without going into the code first, can you tell us exactly what this code is trying to achieve? A double `Do While` loop is a bit extreme especially when you're trying to compare and copy/paste cells. ;)

Comment: Basically, the data starting at L14 consists on invoice numbers. The data starting at R1 also consists of invoice numbers and the data to the left of it in Q1 are the invoice numbers that were merged in the invoice in R. This can occur more than once so Vlookup won't work. The copy and paste code hopefully copies the data in the line A-L where there is a match and pastes it at the bottom, which is held in EndOfCredits. The Value in Q is then pasted in place of the value in L.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you attach some screenshot or show how your data looks like. I have a sample code ready and I want to test it before I post a solution. Also I can see few other errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should run as soon as conditions directly use the cells content (i.e. having ".Text" or ".Value" added to the range):

```
Do While BlankCell.Text <> ""
    Do While SpareCell.Text <> ""
        If BlankCell.Offset(Count).Text = SpareCell.Offset(Count2).Text Then
```

BTW, you should apply such a method also if accessing a single cell's content:
`BlankCell.Offset(EndOfCredits).Value = SpareCell.Offset(Count2, -1).Value`

Best regards, Kawi42